# Why doesn't Stack Apps have its own meta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta, stackapps, per-site-meta

Now that all SE sites have their own meta site, **why doesn't Stack Apps have a meta?**

Sure, Stack Apps is somewhat of a limited site (or rather, a site about a limited subject), so by some counts, it might not need a meta. However, I think there are some things that could be discussed about how Stack Apps should be run and there is no good place to do that now. Thus, I support the creation of a Stack Apps meta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think Stack Apps is a small and focused enough community it can support the handful of meta traffic it will need, on the site itself.

Comment: What StackApps needs is moderators.

Comment: If any Stack Apps meta questions appear here on meta.so should they be migrated to stackapps?

Comment: Okay, so that was almost 7 years ago. Does Stackapps _still_ not need a meta?