# How does one earn the [convention] badge on Stack Apps?

Tags: support, badges, meta, per-site-meta, stackapps

I was looking through the list of badges on Stack Apps and ran across the [convention badge](https://stackapps.com/badges/87/convention). The concept of the convention badge is great - it encourages participation in a site's meta. However, [there is no Meta exclusively for Stack Apps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60092/why-doesnt-stack-apps-have-its-own-meta).

The link next to the badge description takes you here, so I can only assume this is Stack Apps's Meta. If that be the case, then I should have earned the badge by this point.

I am suggesting one of the following corrections be made:

- Award the badge according to Meta participation *here* on Meta.SO.
- Remove the badge from the list of badges on Stack Apps if it cannot be earned.

Comment: Next, you'll be asking about the Precognitive badge on the trilogy sites, which is impossible to gain. :-P Me personally? I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: I'm not worrying about it - I just think that it needs to be addressed for consistency's sake.

Comment: Similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges/71737#71737

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Also `quorum`. If the answer is like the answer to the post Popular Demand linked (to advertise Meta), just `quorum` would suffice for the purpose; there is no reason to have two unachievable badges.

Answer (score 4):

The badge is present on all sites, that's how we've chosen to standardize them, intentionally.  For example the [Precognitive badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/892/precognitive) on Stack Overflow cannot be awarded either.  We thought it was more confusing to hide them selectively than not award them selectively.