# The black hole known as Meta Stack Apps

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta, help-center, stackapps

Firstly, [there isn't a Meta for Stack Apps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60092/why-doesnt-stack-apps-have-its-own-meta).

However, [Stack Apps' help centre](https://stackapps.com/help/whats-meta) seems to disagree:

> Meta Stack Apps is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Stack Apps rather than discussing Stack Exchange API, app, or script itself.

Sure it is! `;)`

> your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Apps

Mhmm... if you say so!

Comment: Are you asking for a Meta.SA, or are you asking for the description to be changed?

Comment: @EmrakultheAeonsTorn The description to be changed.

Comment: @Danny think that better to remove the "whats-meta" page from the help center of sites without Meta site.

Comment: Stack Apps' meta link (or feedback link, depending on rep), leads to MSO. Perhaps the text should be updated to point to MSO as well.

Comment: "your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Apps" - Technically this is true, since Stack Apps is itself Meta Stack Apps. But the rest is just misleading.

Comment: @TimStone That's even more confusing, since all the links to Meta go to Meta Stack Overflow. Which should we use for Meta? MSO or SA?

Comment: I'm not sure why the links point here, I was [under the impression](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60092/why-doesnt-stack-apps-have-its-own-meta/60099#60099) (and would prefer, from an administrative standpoint) that meta-content for Stack Apps should be posted on Stack Apps.

Comment: @TimStone As well as the links pointing here, there are 67 questions here tagged [stackapps]. I think the help centre page needs a little rewrite.

Comment: Oh the irony, someone trying to close this as *pertains to a specific site*; as if you could ask this on the Stack Apps Meta.. Voted to leave open for obvious reasons.

Comment: Just giving this question a friendly bump! Either the text needs changing, or it's time Stack Apps got a Meta - I'd be the first to volunteer to be a mod :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Stack Apps have its own meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60092/why-doesnt-stack-apps-have-its-own-meta)

Comment: @Duh-Wayne-101: Not really. That's asking about the *existence of* a meta; this is primarily asking for *the help text* to be changed.

Answer (score -3):

I think that most of the users that are on Stack Apps know what is going on. It isn't exactly the easiest site to find, and it is hard to know what should actually be posted on there. For me to find out about stack apps, I just heard about all these userscripts, and by that point, I knew about the network. So while it is a valid point, I don't think that it is necessary to do right at the moment

Comment: So leave the text badly worded; is that your suggestion?

Comment: I'm just saying that it isn't pertinent to fix right at the moment