# Shouldn't the questions about Stack Apps be closed as off-topic there?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

Today I have voted to close the question about Stack Apps: [The black hole known as Meta Stack Apps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185521/the-black-hole-known-as-meta-stack-apps).

I noticed that everyone who [reviewed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close/32976) this question in close votes review left open it.

So I wondered, aren't the questions about Stack Apps off-topic there because "pertain to specific site", like questions about (for example) Stack Overflow are?

Comment: No, because Stack Apps *has no Meta*. *This* site is the Meta site for Stack Apps.

Comment: @Martijn http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/meta

Comment: How did you think that trying to close 'there is no Meta for Stack Apps' with 'should be posted to your own Meta' was going to go down?

Comment: This site has also been the Meta for Stack Apps for time immemorial. It is fine to post Stack Apps meta posts here too. Personally, I never liked the use of a `meta` tag on Stack Apps, but that's not under discussion here.

Comment: @Martijn "This site has also been the Meta for Stack Apps for time immemorial" - and also it was Meta for Stack Overflow. However its not fine to post question there pertaining only to SO anymore.

Comment: Nope, but Stack Overflow meta issues drowned out anything else here, which is why it was given their own Meta. Careers has no Meta either, posts about that site are on topic here.

Comment: @Martijn So what? Stack Apps has meta now, it is Stack Apps.

Comment: Stack Apps has no dedicated Meta. It may have a `meta` *tag*, but that's rather ineffectual and not really discoverable. I'm not sure that anyone is monitoring it even, it is just a black hole.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Actually Stack Apps is supposed to be its own meta. Especially for issues concerning content on Stack Apps, I'd much rather it was posted there so I can tag it accordingly when resolved, etc. For bug reports and the like, my opinion is the same as Anna's answer (although this often leads to duplication, which I guess is a little undesirable).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "applies to a specific site" close reason is primarily intended to prevent folks from bringing *discussions* that belong on a particular Q&A site here. Things like "why was my question closed" and "how can we promote ourselves better".

Bug reports and whatnot are fine no matter where they're reported. Shuffling those around to satisfy a strict interpretation of a close reason doesn't do anything productive.

Having said that, Stack Apps doesn't have a meta, or even a community the same way Q&A sites do. It serves a special purpose in our network and questions about it are welcome here.

Comment: "Having said that, Stack Apps doesn't have a meta" - So maybe port all the questions from Stack Apps with [meta] tag there (I guess it can be done by devs, because most questions are older than 60 days)?

Comment: @nicael It literally doesn't matter. I'm not as big a fan of busywork as you are. :)

Comment: What? Do I really look like a fan of busywork?

Comment: @nicael You're the one proposing someone sorts through the questions in the [meta] tag on Stack Apps and moves some of them here. Well, you said "all", but I doubt all would actually be a fit here. What would that even accomplish? Most of them are probably old, resolved, etc.

Comment: "What would that even accomplish?" - dunno, maybe get more attention? Just make me a mod there, I'll see what questions to port :)

Comment: Heh, I knew Shog migrated [my triage question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278407/voting-is-borked-in-triage-review-queue) to MSO just [to get taxonomist](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2732581#2732581).