# 'Meta user' link missing on the Stack Apps profile page

Tags: discussion, bug, meta, stackapps

I am a newbie in using the Stack Apps website. When I visit my profile on this website I can't see the 'Meta user' link on the left side of the 'Network profile' link.

Please see the below image:

[image]

Comment: Related  [Why doesn't Stack Apps have its own meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60092/312043)

Comment: As the duplicate says, Stack Apps doesn't have a per-site meta, so you won't see a link to the meta profile there.